# React JS WYSIWUG Saving

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wysiwyg

Looking for helping on creating / implementing a WYSIWYG Email Creation tool in my React JS application. I have tried using Redactor and also alloyEditor, but am having trouble with them as redactor is primarily built of JQuery and alloyEditor doesn't work on iPads.

I believe my problem is loading in, via ajax HTML content into them as they are not formatted in React code.

Even after this issue, every `<div>` has `data-reactid` peppered through it.

Is there an existing example, or someone that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: I use promises to wait until all the data is loaded. Then extract it in an array. Then I map all the content of that array into separate react components and give them individual keys as props.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this module [React-Quill](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill)

After you get response from Ajax request pass it to

`<CustomQuill value={AjaxResponseHtml} />`

```
var ReactQuill = require('react-quill');
var CustomQuill = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ ReactQuill.Mixin ],

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var editor = this.createEditor(
      this.getEditorElement(),
      this.getEditorConfig()
    );
    this.setState({ editor:editor });
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    if ('value' in nextProps && nextProps.value !== this.props.value) {
      this.setEditorContents(this.state.editor, nextProps.value);
    }
  },

  /* ... */
});
```